# Export query result into json file

Tags: javascript, php, json, file, export

I need to export the data extracted from database by php into json file to have output in json file like this. I need a line break between each line.

"ID":"id.",
"Name":"name",

this is my query which already has id and name. But i have no idea anymore how to export them as a file.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['id'];
echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: try json_encode() function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = [];    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

$txt = json_encode($data);

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $txt);

fclose($myfile);
```

Answer will be like this:

```
[
    { "id": "idvalue", "name": "namevalue" },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. With json_encode, i cant have line break beween each row. Actually, its what i really need to have. Any idea to hv line break after each row in json file? I tried with echo "\n" or echo "\r \n" or echo "\\n", but no luck.